# Hide product price if zero

Tags: php, html, e-commerce

Currently I am working on a webshop. I added the following code in the search.php file.

```
<span id="old_product_price_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>">
<?php echo wpsc_product_normal_price(); ?></span>
```

I tried to make an if/else statement that if the price is € 0,00, the price gets hidden. I want to add this, because the pages like contact etc, get standard the price € 0,00. I tried the following code:

```
<?php if (wpsc_product_normal_price() == "€ 0,00") : ?>   
<span><?php echo ""></span>
<?php else : ?> <span id="old_product_price_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>">
<?php echo wpsc_product_normal_price(); ?></span>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the actual result of wpsc_product_normal_price()?  In other words does it return "€ 0,00" or simply "0,00" or even "0" ?

Comment: Where does your endif condition occur?

Comment: I added the endif after this code. On the page it shows 0 as: € 0,00

Comment: Are you sure wpsc_product_normal_price() doesn't return the price contained in a span element? Like `<span class='pricedisplay'>€ 0,00</span>`.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a `?` in the second line of your second code snippet. Corrected code:

```
<?php if (wpsc_product_normal_price() == "€ 0,00") : ?>   
<span><?php echo ""; ?></span>
<?php else : ?> <span id="old_product_price_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>">
<?php echo wpsc_product_normal_price(); ?></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it still doesn't do anything. It still shows the € 0,00. I tried instead of € 0,00 also 0, € 0.00. Still it doesn't go away.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<?php if ("€ 0,00" == wpsc_product_normal_price ()) { ?>

<span></span>

<?php } else { ?>

<span id="old_product_price_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>">
    <?php echo wpsc_product_normal_price(); ?>
</span>

<?php } ?>
```

If the value is actually 0,00 (should be 0.00 in the database, I would presume? and formatted to 0,00 to make it euro-friendly through the above function?)

```
// replace with 0.00 or 0,00 and try these
<?php if ("0,00" == wpsc_product_normal_price ()) { ?>

<span></span>

<?php } else { ?>

<span id="old_product_price_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>">
    <?php echo wpsc_product_normal_price(); ?>
</span>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Tried both, still doesn't work. I will try to look inside the database and find out what number it shows there.

Comment: I found this on the internet: http://jamestylerpolitics.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/display-free-items-in-appcloud-theme/ I tried it, but it also won't work.

Comment: Is there any other code than the code in your query?  Can you post a full script that fails? and the output?